# Building temporal correlation model by a dataset and calibrating the model with other dataset

Tags: modeling, dataset

On one hand,

I have a temperature time series data (dataset1) for a week and I want to build the temporal correlation model by using time-series analysis and performing the prediction for oncoming values. The data is not sufficient and doesn't include seasonal and diurnal patterns to result accurate predictions.

On the other hand,

I have an other source of data (dataset2) which is a little bit far from the study area but include sufficient amount of data which represent seasonal and diurnal effects.

**My question**:

I am writing to ask whether it is possible to build the temporal correlation model based on the dataset2 and calibrating it by dataset1?  (The calibrating is essential since the dataset2 is not as local as dataset1.)

What I want is to gain the seasonal and daily patterns from the large dataset (dataset2) and perform the predictions based on the dataset1 which are local for the study area. In other words, using dataset2 to build the temporal correlation modeling and performing the predictions based on that cannot give the accurate results.